# xrandr and xbacklight not changing brightness in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, xrandr, backlight

I reinstalled NVIDIA drivers on my Dell laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 and xbacklight stopped working.

I never managed before to adjust brightness using system shortcut keys (changing GRUB settings didn't help), but creating my own shortcuts for `xbacklight -dec 10` and `xbacklight -inc 10` helped.
But after I reinstalled NVIDIA drivers even this method stopped working.

Trying `xrandr --output [your display] --brightness 0.8`, I get the output: `xrandr: Gamma size is 0.`.

Using `sudo find /sys -type f -name brightness` I get:

```
/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4/input4::capslock/brightness
/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4/input4::scrolllock/brightness
/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4/input4::numlock/brightness
/sys/devices/platform/dell-laptop/backlight/dell_backlight/brightness
/sys/devices/platform/dell-laptop/leds/dell::kbd_backlight/brightness
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.3/leds/phy0-led/brightness
```

`xrandr --verbose` gives:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (0x2b2) normal (normal) 0mm x 0mm
    Identifier: 0x2b1
    Timestamp:  30791
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       0
    CRTCs:      0
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    _MUTTER_PRESENTATION_OUTPUT: 0 
  1920x1080 (0x2b2) 159.667MHz *current
        h: width  1920 start    0 end    0 total 1920 skew    0 clock  83.16KHz
        v: height 1080 start    0 end    0 total 1080           clock  77.00Hz
```

I have already tried reinstalling xrandr and xbacklight, but it did not change anything.
Neither did help adding device to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` the following way:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier    "0x2b1"
    Driver        "intel"
    Option        "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
EndSection
```

Comment: Seems you have "dell backlight " device not " intel backlight " so your xorg.conf file is wrong . Please revert it to what it was . What if you write the brightness number ( between 0 and /sys/devices/platform/dell-laptop/backlight/dell_backlight/max_brightness ) to the file "/sys/devices/platform/dell-laptop/backlight/dell_backlight/brightness" ? It requires root access , but if that worked for you , please tell me to suggest the second step to generate a shortcut for it.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi, changing number in that file also does not help.
About "xorg.conf": I removed this whole "Device" section so that file is now as it was. But I noticed that I already have Section "Screen" there, and it also has Option "Backlight "intel_backlight". What is more, after I reinstalled the drivers my "Displays" menu in Settings has actually changed: now my display is seen as "Unknown Display" and previously it was something like "Default Display". Maybe the problem somehow is in display recognition?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's wrong with `xbacklight`, but it doesn't work for me either. What does work for me is `brightnessctl`.  I installed that program, and then configured my desktop environment with shortcuts for `brightnessctl -q s +5%` (brightness up), `brightnessctl -q s 5%-` (brightness down), `brightnessctl -q s100%` (brightness max).

In Ubuntu, I think you'll want to install the additional package `brightnessctl-udev` and add yourself to the `video` group.

Comment: Thank you, @alvherre! Unfortunately, this did not work for me.

Comment: I think the `xrandr` error message about "gamma" is closely related.  I do not get that message, and adjusting brightness with `xrandr` does work for me, so clearly you have a problem that I do not.  I wonder if the problem is in the Nvidia driver ... Did you try installing Nouveau?